# C# concurrent List access

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, concurrency

There is this class, that allows to write data into stream in one Thread and read in multiple Threads.

The main purpose it support streaming, eg. network or audio stream, reading it and processing in multiple threads allowing for data to come as it goes.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345105/Memory-Stream-Multiplexer-write-and-read-from-many?msg=4665022#xx4665022xx

MemoryStreamMultiplexer writes data chunk by chunk and stores into `List<byte[]> _Buffer` variable.

This _Buffer is then passed into MemoryStreamReader like this:

```
new MemoryStreamReader(_Buffer, dataReady, finished);
```

MemoryStreamReader reads byte[] arrays stored in this _Buffer list one my one, checking that data is present

```
if (_bufferIndex < _bufferList.Count)
{
  return ReadInternal(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

ReadInternal gets the next buffer from _Buffer list and reads it afterwards

```
byte[] currentBuffer = _bufferList[_bufferIndex];
```

Now, here is the problem: at random, currentBuffer becomes null, that results in NullReferenceException later.

In debug, while currentBuffer is stated to be null, if I check the value in _bufferList[_bufferIndex] - valid array is returned. So this seems to be some memory or concurrency issue.

My thoughts are that at some point List decides to change it's Capacity, re-allocating internal array. While we are still reading the List, it returns null because memory address had already changed but no data was yet copied into it.

The question is - how to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly extended [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Since you are using C# (gc, memory will get freed automatically) I would suggest creating each Consumer with a separate synchronized queue, then posting the same data array to each of those queues. Since the data will be read only after it is pushed it is perfectly safe for multiple threads to access it simultaneously.

Using a ConcurrentQueue will spare you the worry for synchronization, which will in turn save you a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It might be worthy with small amounts of data, but with a stream - any size of data can be passed through implementation. So, if we post the same data array to multiple queues - it will increase memory consumption multiple times and may result in serious problems if initial data is large

Comment: Also, ConcurrentQueue<T> should be used instead of a synchronized queue.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, that that in _Buffer may change on the fly - if we are reading Network, for example. So pushing data to a ConcurentQueue isn't an option - we will get stale data without any updates

Comment: @AAverin My idea was to push data after a whole chunk has already been received. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: @dcastro care to say why? your comment provides no justification.

Comment: @Dariusz, thanks. I've modified my question to mention that streaming is required.

Comment: The synchronized queue does not guarantee thread-safety in many situations, whereas the ConcurrentQueue does. From your link to the synchronized queue MSDN doc: "Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure.". However, the ConcurrentQueue creates a snapshot/copy of the queue you can safely enumerate.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287144.aspx: "The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the queue. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after GetEnumerator was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the queue."